# Show and hide selected div element via .map()

Tags: reactjs

Every video I've seen regarding to showing or hiding a div, is quite not effective at all if you're making use of a state that's based on true or false, thus when a button is clicked through the `.map()` all elements that are hidden would be shown, therefore it wouldn't be in great use of all, I guess that's why the element's index should be in use to determine which element should shown or hidden right?

**Scenario**

So I'm building a social platform for a learning experience, where I map through all my posts in an array, once I click my comment Icon, the comments should be shown for that post, but unfortunately I'm unable to find a solution regarding to the use of functional components.

this is what I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import "../../styles/private/dashboard.css";
import DashboardHeader from "../../components/private/templates/header";
import DashboardSidebar from "../../components/private/templates/sidebar";
import ImageSearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ImageSearch";
import VideoLibraryIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VideoLibrary";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { newPost } from "../../redux/actions/posts/new-post";
import { likePost } from "../../redux/actions/posts/like-post";
import { getPosts } from "../../redux/actions/posts/get-posts";
import { unlikePost } from "../../redux/actions/posts/unlike-post";
import { getPostLikes } from "../../redux/actions/posts/get-likes";
import { likePostComment } from "../../redux/actions/posts/like-comment";
import { unlikePostComment } from "../../redux/actions/posts/unlike-comment";
import { newPostComment } from "../../redux/actions/posts/new-post-comment";
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutline";
import LoopIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Loop";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import FlipMove from "react-flip-move";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");

function Dashboard({
  history,
  getPost,
  getLike,
  getAllPosts,
  getAllLikes,
  likePosts,
  unlikePosts,
}) {
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState({});
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");
  const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [comment, setComment] = useState();
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { user } = userLogin;
  const [uname, setUname] = useState(user.name);
  const [upic, setUpic] = useState(user.pic);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cookies.get("authToken")) {
      history.push("/login");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/post/posts", config).then((response) => {
      setPosts(response.data);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (item) => {
      setPosts((oldPosts) => {
        const findItem = oldPosts.find((post) => post._id === item._id);
        if (findItem) {
          return oldPosts.map((post) => (post._id === item._id ? item : post));
        } else {
          return [item, ...oldPosts];
        }
      });
    };

    socket.on("posts", handler);
    return () => socket.off("posts", handler);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const postHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(newPost(uname, upic, messages, media));
    setMessages("");
  };

  const LikePost = (postId) => {
    likePosts(postId, user._id, user.name, user.pic);
  };

  const UnlikePost = (postId) => {
    unlikePosts(postId);
  };

  const submitComment = (postId) => {
    dispatch(newPostComment(postId, uname, upic, comment));
    setComment("");
  };

  const LikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
    dispatch(likePostComment(postId, commentId, user._id, user.name, user.pic));
  };

  const UnlikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
    dispatch(unlikePostComment(postId, commentId));
  };

  return error ? (
    <span>{error}</span>
  ) : (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <DashboardHeader />
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        <div className="dashboard__sidebar">
          <DashboardSidebar />
        </div>
        <div className="dashboard__content">
          <div className="dashboard__contentLeft">
            <div className="dashboard__messenger">
              <div className="dashboard__messengerTop">
                <Avatar src={user.pic} className="dashboard__messengerAvatar" />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${user.name}`}
                  value={messages}
                  onChange={(e) => setMessages(e.target.value)}
                />
                <SendIcon
                  className="dashboard__messengerPostButton"
                  onClick={postHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="dashboard__messengerBottom">
                <ImageSearchIcon
                  className="dashboard__messengerImageIcon"
                  value={media}
                  onChange={(e) => setMedia((e) => e.target.value)}
                />
                <VideoLibraryIcon className="dashboard__messengerVideoIcon" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="dashboard__postsContainer">
              <FlipMove>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                  <div className="dashboard__post" key={i}>
                    <MoreHorizIcon className="dashboard__postOptions" />
                    <div className="dashboard__postTop">
                      <Avatar
                        className="dashboard__postUserPic"
                        src={post.upic}
                      />
                      <h3>{post.uname}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboard__postBottom">
                      <p>{post.message}</p>
                      {media === null ? (
                        ""
                      ) : (
                        <div className="dashboard__postMedia">{media}</div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboard__postActions">
                      {toggle ? (
                        <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon
                          onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
                          className="dashboard__actionComment"
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon
                          onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
                          className="dashboard__actionComment"
                        />
                      )}
                      <label
                        id="totalLikes"
                        className="dashboard__comments"
                        style={{ color: "forestgreen" }}
                      >
                        {post.commentCount}
                      </label>

                      {post.likes.find((like) => like.uid === user._id) ? (
                        <FavoriteIcon
                          onClick={() => UnlikePost(post._id)}
                          className="dashboard__actionUnlike"
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <FavoriteBorderIcon
                          onClick={() => LikePost(post._id)}
                          className="dashboard__actionLike"
                        />
                      )}
                      <label
                        id="totalLikes"
                        className="dashboard__likes"
                        style={{ color: "forestgreen" }}
                      >
                        {post.likeCount}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      className={
                        toggle
                          ? "dashboard__commentContent toggle"
                          : "dashboard__commentContent"
                      }
                    >
                      <div className="dashboard__postComments">
                        {post.comments.map((comment) => (
                          <div
                            key={comment.toString()}
                            className="dashboard__postComment"
                          >
                            <div className="dashboard__postCommentTop">
                              <Avatar src={comment.upic} />
                              <h4>{comment.uname}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <p>{comment.message}</p>
                            <div className="dashboard__postCommentActions">
                              {comment.likes.find(
                                (like) => like.uid === user._id
                              ) ? (
                                <FavoriteIcon
                                  onClick={() =>
                                    UnlikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)
                                  }
                                  className="dashboard__actionUnlike"
                                />
                              ) : (
                                <FavoriteBorderIcon
                                  onClick={() =>
                                    LikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)
                                  }
                                  className="dashboard__actionLike"
                                />
                              )}
                              <label
                                id="totalLikes"
                                className="dashboard__likes"
                                style={{ color: "forestgreen" }}
                              >
                                {comment.likeCount}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      </div>

                      <div className="dashboard__commentInput">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Comment post"
                          value={comment}
                          onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <button onClick={() => submitComment(post._id)}>
                          Send
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </FlipMove>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="dashboardContentRight"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getLike: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  getPost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  likePost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  unlikePost: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    getPost: getPosts(state),
    getLike: getPostLikes(state),
    likePosts: likePost(state),
    unlikePosts: unlikePost(state),
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAllPosts: (posts) => dispatch(getPosts(posts)),
    getAllLikes: (likes) => dispatch(getPostLikes(likes)),
    likePosts: (like) => dispatch(likePost(like)),
    unlikePosts: (like) => dispatch(unlikePost(like)),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

**Extra**

[here is a unlisted video](https://youtu.be/AG9u9uFvMTI) from youtube, just for incase that you do not understand.

Comment: this is because you calling setToggle against your whole Dashboard. Just create a component named `<Post/>` and use your toggle there

Comment: so if i understand you wish to open only the one you click right ? and not all others ?

Comment: @DarioRega yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code going there... You should refactor that i smaller component, more easier to read and maintainability.

You can check there the answer i posted, it's the same core issue:
[The axios delete functionality is only deleting last user from table, not the one I click on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539104/the-axios-delete-functionality-is-only-deleting-last-user-from-table-not-the-on/69539535#69539535)

your toggle is based on the global state, so each post doesn't have its proper way to see if it's open or not.That's why it will open everything

You need to tell which one is open and which ones aren't.

Here i refactored your code to make it work with multiple boxes open, i didn't test it on codesandbox, i let you try, but it wasn't big changes, so it should works.

Please pay attention to these news changes:

- useState property openBoxes
- Method toggleCommentBox
- Method isCommentBoxOpen

I then replaced in your jsx the way you check if the comment box is open or not.

```
    function Dashboard({
                       history,
                       getPost,
                       getLike,
                       getAllPosts,
                       getAllLikes,
                       likePosts,
                       unlikePosts,
                   }) {
    const [participants, setParticipants] = useState({});
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const [openBoxes, setOpenBoxes] = useState([]);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");
    const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [comment, setComment] = useState();
    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
    const {user} = userLogin;
    const [uname, setUname] = useState(user.name);
    const [upic, setUpic] = useState(user.pic);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        },
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!cookies.get("authToken")) {
            history.push("/login");
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [history]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/post/posts", config).then((response) => {
            setPosts(response.data);
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = (item) => {
            setPosts((oldPosts) => {
                const findItem = oldPosts.find((post) => post._id === item._id);
                if (findItem) {
                    return oldPosts.map((post) => (post._id === item._id ? item : post));
                } else {
                    return [item, ...oldPosts];
                }
            });
        };

        socket.on("posts", handler);
        return () => socket.off("posts", handler);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
    
    /*
        Toggle state of post boxes
     */
    const toggleCommentBox = postId => {
        if(openBoxes.includes(postId)){
            setOpenBoxes(openBoxes.filter(x => x !== postId))
        } else {
            setOpenBoxes([...openBoxes, postId])
        }
    }
    /*
        Returns boolean if comment box is open on this post
     */
    const isCommentBoxOpen = postId => openBoxes.includes(postId)
    
    const postHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(newPost(uname, upic, messages, media));
        setMessages("");
    };

    const LikePost = (postId) => {
        likePosts(postId, user._id, user.name, user.pic);
    };

    const UnlikePost = (postId) => {
        unlikePosts(postId);
    };

    const submitComment = (postId) => {
        dispatch(newPostComment(postId, uname, upic, comment));
        setComment("");
    };

    const LikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
        dispatch(likePostComment(postId, commentId, user._id, user.name, user.pic));
    };

    const UnlikeCommentPost = (postId, commentId) => {
        dispatch(unlikePostComment(postId, commentId));
    };

    return error ? (
        <span>{error}</span>
    ) : (
        <div className="dashboard">
            <DashboardHeader/>
            <div className="dashboard__container">
                <div className="dashboard__sidebar">
                    <DashboardSidebar/>
                </div>
                <div className="dashboard__content">
                    <div className="dashboard__contentLeft">
                        <div className="dashboard__messenger">
                            <div className="dashboard__messengerTop">
                                <Avatar src={user.pic} className="dashboard__messengerAvatar"/>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${user.name}`}
                                    value={messages}
                                    onChange={(e) => setMessages(e.target.value)}
                                />
                                <SendIcon
                                    className="dashboard__messengerPostButton"
                                    onClick={postHandler}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="dashboard__messengerBottom">
                                <ImageSearchIcon
                                    className="dashboard__messengerImageIcon"
                                    value={media}
                                    onChange={(e) => setMedia((e) => e.target.value)}
                                />
                                <VideoLibraryIcon className="dashboard__messengerVideoIcon"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="dashboard__postsContainer">
                            <FlipMove>
                                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                                    <div className="dashboard__post" key={i}>
                                        <MoreHorizIcon className="dashboard__postOptions"/>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postTop">
                                            <Avatar
                                                className="dashboard__postUserPic"
                                                src={post.upic}
                                            />
                                            <h3>{post.uname}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postBottom">
                                            <p>{post.message}</p>
                                            {media === null ? (
                                                ""
                                            ) : (
                                                <div className="dashboard__postMedia">{media}</div>
                                            )}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="dashboard__postActions">
                                            {isCommentBoxOpen(post.id) ? (
                                                <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon
                                                    onClick={() => toggleCommentBox(post._id)}
                                                    className="dashboard__actionComment"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon
                                                    onClick={() => toggleCommentBox(post._id)}
                                                    className="dashboard__actionComment"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            <label
                                                id="totalLikes"
                                                className="dashboard__comments"
                                                style={{color: "forestgreen"}}
                                            >
                                                {post.commentCount}
                                            </label>

                                            {post.likes.find((like) => like.uid === user._id) ? (
                                                <FavoriteIcon
                                                    onClick={() => UnlikePost(post._id)}
                                                    className="dashboard__actionUnlike"
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <FavoriteBorderIcon
                                                    onClick={() => LikePost(post._id)}
                                                    className="dashboard__actionLike"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            <label
                                                id="totalLikes"
                                                className="dashboard__likes"
                                                style={{color: "forestgreen"}}
                                            >
                                                {post.likeCount}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            className={
                                                toggle
                                                    ? "dashboard__commentContent toggle"
                                                    : "dashboard__commentContent"
                                            }
                                        >
                                            <div className="dashboard__postComments">
                                                {post.comments.map((comment) => (
                                                    <div
                                                        key={comment.toString()}
                                                        className="dashboard__postComment"
                                                    >
                                                        <div className="dashboard__postCommentTop">
                                                            <Avatar src={comment.upic}/>
                                                            <h4>{comment.uname}</h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p>{comment.message}</p>
                                                        <div className="dashboard__postCommentActions">
                                                            {comment.likes.find(
                                                                (like) => like.uid === user._id
                                                            ) ? (
                                                                <FavoriteIcon
                                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                                        UnlikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)
                                                                    }
                                                                    className="dashboard__actionUnlike"
                                                                />
                                                            ) : (
                                                                <FavoriteBorderIcon
                                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                                        LikeCommentPost(post._id, comment._id)
                                                                    }
                                                                    className="dashboard__actionLike"
                                                                />
                                                            )}
                                                            <label
                                                                id="totalLikes"
                                                                className="dashboard__likes"
                                                                style={{color: "forestgreen"}}
                                                            >
                                                                {comment.likeCount}
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                ))}
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="dashboard__commentInput">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    placeholder="Comment post"
                                                    value={comment}
                                                    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                                                />
                                                <button onClick={() => submitComment(post._id)}>
                                                    Send
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </FlipMove>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboardContentRight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Let me know if it works or you need more explanation
```

Comment: Hey Dario, I just like to say thank you for the help and time!! I apologise for the late response, I understand that the code needs to be refactored/cleaned-up a bit and I will take that into consideration; much appreciated!