# The axios delete functionality is only deleting last user from table, not the one I click on

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

So like the title says, the axios.delete functionality is only deleting the last user from table, and not the one I click on. Let me describe you the problem I have.

So in one component that I made called TableComponent.js, I am fetching users from API and inserting them inside Material UI table. Now I added to each user in the table, a delete button that when clicked on opens a Material UI modal that is going to say "Are you sure you want to delete this user?" and a DELETE button, that when clicked on deletes the user from table.

Now in the other component that I called DeleteUser.js, I have put that modal and also a function that deletes the users from table, the issue I have right now is that this function only deletes the last user, and not the one I clicked on, to be precise the 5th one out of 5 that are presented on table.

Here is TableComponent.js:

```
   {data.data.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map((apiData, index) => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableCell align="left" style={{ paddingLeft: 40 }}>
              <EditLink
                to={{
                  pathname: "/edit",
                  user: {
                    title: "Edit User",
                    id: apiData.id,
                    name: apiData.name,
                    email: apiData.email,
                    status: apiData.status,
                    gender: apiData.gender,
                    method: "put",
                  },
                }}
              >
                {apiData.name}
              </EditLink>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{apiData.email}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{apiData.status}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{apiData.gender}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{roles}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ paddingRight: 40 }}>
              <RoleButton onClick={handleRoleChange}>
                {roles === "Admin" ? "Set as User" : "Set as Admin"}
              </RoleButton>
              <button onClick={setOpen}>  // section for deleting users
                <AiFillDelete />
                <DeleteUser open={open} userID={apiData.id} />
              </button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
```

And here is the DeleteUser.js:

```
const Container = styled.div``;

const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

const handleDeleteUser = (id) => {
  axios
    .delete(`https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Bearer my token goes here",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response));
};

const DeleteUser = ({ open, onClose, userID }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={onClose}>
        <Box sx={style}>
          <h1>tets</h1>
          <button onClick={() => handleDeleteUser(userID)}>Delete</button>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default DeleteUser;
```

Anyone knows what is the issue here?

This happens when I try to alert the id of first user:

[image]

But here is it's id:

[image]

If I pressed on the first one, I would get the id of the last one:

[image]

Comment: The id that gets passed, is that of the last row or the one you clicked on?
Asking this to know which end has the issue.

Comment: Well when I console.log the id's that get passed to DeleteUser.js component, I get all of them, but when I click on delete button inside the delete modal, only the last one gets deleted. So the last row.

Comment: On your API does the correct user get deleted or it's wrong aswell ? If it's only on front end it might be because of your slice. Could you try to change your key={apiData.id} to check out ?

Comment: On the API the last one gets deleted, or to be precise the wrong one.

Comment: @DarioRega i don't think this is the issue with API, because if I manually delete the user without passing the id's to other component it works perfectly. This has to be issue with the way I am sending id's to other component.

Comment: Strange... Could you verify that the id passed as props is the same as the one you click ? try to put the {apiData.id} instead of email or something. Then on your handleDeleteUser set an alert with the id as value to check if they are the same

Comment: @DarioRega oh I did that previously, and again the last one shows, even though I am pressing on the first user

Comment: Could you show a screen of the alert with the value inside and aswell of the id you clicked please

Comment: There you go, I have edited the question.

Comment: Great but could you aswell show the UI on the row you clicked with the ID and aswell the network tab call request headers to compare everything please

Comment: @DarioRega Like I said previously, the fact that it is alerting only the last row, tells me that the issue is with the way I am sending the id's to other component.

Comment: i think i know why ! what does your setOpen does ? i see that you use the open props to tell if the DeleteUser is open, but i think he doesn't know which one it is. Show me the setopen function and i'll try to come with a fix for you

Comment: SetOpen is used with useToggle custom hook, I don't think that has any impact on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238057/discussion-between-dariorega-and-ahmedskulj10).

Comment: Overall, your approach is not that idea. I would write everything in a different way. Let me find a codesandbox of my approach to this.

Comment: Move your DeleteUser component out of the map and keep state of id. On button click  update your states like setOpen(true) and setId(apiData.id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onClick={setOpen}>  // section for deleting users
  <AiFillDelete />
  <DeleteUser open={open} userID={apiData.id} />
</button>
```

If you look right there your onClick={setOpen} will toggle your state value that the modal is open, behind you pass the open props to the DeleteUser modal, but reacts doesn't know which one is open, it will open all of them, or open the first one/last one he has i guess.

You need to specify which DeleteUser modal you wish to display, to fix that you have two possiblities:
Create a state property

```
const [currentModalOpen,setCurrentModalOpen] = useState(null)
```

on your onClick handler, you pass the id as a reference, `onClick{() =>setCurrentModalOpen(apiData.id)}`

then on for your component DeleteUser

```
 <DeleteUser open={currentModalOpen === apiData.id} userID={apiData.id} onClose={() => setCurrentModalOpen(null)}/>
```

Doing so open will always be false if the current row clicked is not the same as the current id.

Tell me if it works and if you need more explication !